# How to query the max quantity of grouped records and display that date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a view that sums the quantity of items based on item and date. I now want to query from those results the Max(Quantity) along with the date. If Max(Quantity) has multiple dates, want to display oldest.  Only want the one record. Here is a data example:

```
Example 1
Item       quantity       Date
I1         100            1/1/2010
I1         100            2/1/2010
I1         5              3/1/2010
```

In this case I would only want to see the first record with the oldest date.

Because Using max, need the group by. How can I rewrite this query. Can use store procedure if needed. Will display in a report.

```
Select Item, Max(quantity), LoadDate
from vwArchiveQuantityByLoadDate
where Item = 'I1'
group by Item, LoadDate
order by Item, LoadDate
```

Using SQL Server 2008, Reporting services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one way without using max.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d928f/4)**

```
select top 1 item, quantity, date
from vwArchiveQuantityByLoadDate
where Item = 'I1'
order by quantity desc, date desc
```

Comment: I tried top the wrong way. can't believe it. I will plug this in and give it a try. This query is a subset of the overall data being pulled. I think it will work. I'll let you know.

Comment: That didn't work. It doesn't display the max quantity record. looks like the oldest.

Comment: @jmd There must be more to your example that we aren't seeing. You can experiment with the sql fiddle demo I provided above and see that it works. Add more rows with different dates and values and it still returns the max quantity and then date

Comment: You're correct. My apologies. I did something wrong. It now works. Thank you.